# print passes values to Mysql

Tags: php

i am using this code to add values to database

```
  <?php

$debdes = $_POST['debdes'];
$debamt = $_POST['debamt'];
$crdes  = $_POST['crdes'];
$cramt  = $_POST['cramt'];
$date   = $_POST['date'];
include_once ("db.php");

$ucbook = "INSERT INTO cbook(debdes,debamt,crdes,cramt,date) VALUES ('$debdes','$debamt','$crdes','$cramt','$date');";


if (mysql_query($ucbook))

echo "One Record Updated Successfully with the following details <br/>";


else 

echo mysql_error(); 



?>
```

now i want that when query pass this show me that which values are added like this

"Following record is updated successfully

debamt = 1000
debdes = test

end "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the query does **not fails**, you can just show your values:

---

```
.
.
.
if (mysql_query($ucbook)){

echo "One Record Updated Successfully with the following details <br/>";

echo "debdes=$debdes <br>" ;
echo "debamt=$debamt <br>" ;
echo "crdes=$crdes <br>" ;
echo "cramt=$cramt <br>" ;
echo "date=$date <br>" ;
echo "end";

}
else 
{
echo "Error while inserting data :".mysql_error()."<br/>"; 
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do it:

1. if you one of the fields that you are inserting is a primary key, then search the table for the record you updated, and then display the resultant data.
2. If your primary key is generated automatically using `auto_increment`, then use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Cheers,
jrh

Comment: do you know what a primary key is? do you know what `auto_increment` is?